# Is it possible to create dataframe with sub-headers in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following piece of code:

```
_tmp = {}
_tmp['pre'] = {
    'A2': 10,
    'B2': 15,
    'C2': 20
}
_tmp['diff'] = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 15,
    'C1': 20
}
_tmp['sum'] = {
    'A': 100,
    'B': 150,
    'C': 200
}
```

By performing the following commands:

```
_dff = pd.DataFrame(data=_tmp.values(), index=_tmp.keys())
_dff[['A', 'B', 'C', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2']]
```

I got a result described below:

[image]

However I am interested in knowing whether it is possible to build a structure in pandas like the following:

[image]

Comment: do you NEED the headers `A1`, `B1` etc?

Comment: Yes, I need 3 levels of headers: A, B, C next A1, B1, C1 next A2, B2, C2. Thank you

Comment: pandas doesn't do that... what are you hoping to accomplish with this? you can just use 3 separate dataframes and print them back-to-back though. pandas is for grid-type data, and your model isn't a grid.

Comment: note that you _can_ do multilevel indexes - depending on what you are trying to do, it might get you closer to what you want, but it still won't look like that.

Comment: I anticipated that pandas can't do it :). However, there is very good feature - calculate total in Pandas for each of sub-headers etc

Answer (score 3):

What you're really looking at there is a three dimensional structure, which a dataframe cannot do.  (They're 2D only.)

This leaves you with a couple options:

(1) Multiple dataframes (pre/diff/sum).

```
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(v.items()) for k,v in _tmp.items()}
```

(2) A pandas `Panel` which you can build like:

```
pnl = pd.Panel(dfs)
```

Which is a way of grouping multiple dataframes.

(3) A 3d numpy matrix:

```
>>> pnl.as_matrix()
[[['A1' 10]
  ['C1' 20]
  ['B1' 15]]

 [['C2' 20]
  ['A2' 10]
  ['B2' 15]]

 [['A' 100]
  ['C' 200]
  ['B' 150]]]
```

You're going to have to write a custom print function to get your exact requested output of course, but these would be the ways you can represent your data.