# How to make a nested dictionary keys as a subheaders in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a DataFrame from API via Pandas and some fields consist of nested dictionaries. how to define these dictionaries' keys as submenu of dataframe

[image]

ideally, it would be looks like this
[image]

Comment: If it's only one level nested - you might want to take a look at [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create dataframe with sub-headers in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973087/is-it-possible-to-create-dataframe-with-sub-headers-in-pandas)